# New header every new chapter included in master document

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using Bookclass and created several book chapters (each has its own author). Each book chapter need to have a heading on the first page of the chapter with the name of the book series and year. On the remaining pages of each chapter: even pages have the running title of the chapter and odd pages have authors names. So that is all fine. Now when I try to combine these in one MasterDocument things gets very messy. 
So far I tried the following in the preamble of the masterdocument:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand{\firstpagehead}[1]{Book Series name 2014}
\newcommand{\shortauthor}[1]{ Authors et al}
\newcommand{\runtitle}[1]{Running title}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=1}{\firstpagehead}{\shortauthor} } 
\fancyhead[CE]{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=1}{}{\runtitle}}  
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=1}{}{\textnormal\thepage}}  

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0in}
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

I also tried to put the following lines after table of contents and before each chapter to reset the above three commands

```
\renewcommand{\firstpagehead}[1]{Book Series name 2014}
\renewcommand{\shortauthor}[1]{ new Authors et al}
\renewcommand{\runtitle}[1]{new Running title}
```

The above three renewed commands did not work. I am also struggiling on how to define the first page of each chapter?

Help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you have a master document and all chapters are `\include`d.

So you can do the following:

1. Define your commands in the master document to be empty:

   ```
   \newcommand{\firstpagehead}{}
   \newcommand{\shortauthor}{}
   %\newcommand{\runtitle}{}
   ```

   Note that I removed `[1]` from them since they have no arguments and I commented `\runtitle` since I think it suffices to use `\leftmark`. Change it back if you don't like it.
2. This is the definition of the style `fancy`:

   ```
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyhead[CO]{\shortauthor}
   %\fancyhead[CE]{\runtitle}
   \fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
   \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textnormal\thepage}

   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
   \addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
   \setlength{\footskip}{0in}
   \renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0pt}
   ```
3. This is the redefinition of the style `plain`

   ```
   \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
   \fancyhead{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
   \fancyhead[C]{\firstpagehead}
   }
   ```
4. At the beginning of each `\include`d chapter put something like

   ```
   \renewcommand{\firstpagehead}{1st Book Series name 2014}
   \renewcommand{\shortauthor}{1st Authors et al}
   %\renewcommand{\runtitle}{Running title}
   ```

Use the following MWE to test if it is what you were looking for:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\firstpagehead}{}
\newcommand{\shortauthor}{}
%\newcommand{\runtitle}{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\shortauthor}
%\fancyhead[CE]{\runtitle}
\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textnormal\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0in}
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\firstpagehead}
}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\firstpagehead}{1st Book Series name 2014}
\renewcommand{\shortauthor}{1st Authors et al}
%\renewcommand{\runtitle}{Running title}
\chapter{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-5]

\renewcommand{\firstpagehead}{2nd Book Series name 2014}
\renewcommand{\shortauthor}{2nd Authors et al}
%\renewcommand{\runtitle}{Running title}
\chapter{test}
\lipsum[1]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```